# Раздвоился вывод TextView в Android 13 Samsung

Tags: android, kotlin

Проблема замечена пока только у заказчика на смартфоне, на эмуляторе android 13 все хорошо. Просто не представляю, что это может быть и из-за чего это может быть. На скриншоте вот как это выглядит. Вот код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_task"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_layout_margin"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_card_height"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
                        app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_task_card"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_profile_card_background"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5">

                            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                                android:id="@+id/guideline_top_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivCardLogo"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/task_logo_size"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/task_logo_size"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_task_card_logo"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_top_content"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                tools:src="@drawable/ic_bot_1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvCardTitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/font_arial_bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivCardLogo"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivCardLogo"
                                tools:text="Zadanie #30" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvCardSubscribe"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCardLogo"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivCardLogo"
                                tools:text="Subscribe 180 days" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvCardAward"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/empty_dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_coin"
                                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/tiny_layout_margin"
                                android:drawableTint="@color/colorProfileAction"
                                android:elevation="100dp"
                                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorProfileAction"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivCardLogo"
                                tools:text="10" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:elevation="100dp"
                                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                                android:text="Profit"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorProfileAction"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCardLogo"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvCardAward"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCardAward" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvCardDescription"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/empty_dp"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:paddingStart="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_top_content"
                                tools:text="Найти ыовап оыфвал офывоа фылова лфыова офывлоа фыов адфлыов аофывдал оыфва ло" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/detail"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/empty_dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingStart="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnActivateBot"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnActivateBot"
                                android:text="Подробнее..." />
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnActivateBot"
                                style="@style/AppTheme.Button.Secondary"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                android:text="@string/activate_bot" />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_margin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
                        android:text="@string/bot_progress_title"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/font_arial_bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>

                    <net.makemoney.android.stepview.VerticalStepView
                        android:id="@+id/vertical_step_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_task"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
                    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    tools:title="Zadanie #30">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivTaskInfo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_info_icon"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_info"/>
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/containerAdditionalTasks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_content_top_rounded"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
                        android:text="@string/bot_profit_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAwardAtTheMoment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTransparent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
                        tools:text="@string/task_award_at_the_moment"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:background="@color/colorBalanceDivider"/>
                </FrameLayout>

                <net.makemoney.android.stepview.VerticalStepView
                    android:id="@+id/vertical_step_view_launch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bgInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/infoBackgroundColor"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivInfoClose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_info_close_icon"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvInfoDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:text="@string/info_bot_description"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `android:layout_height="@dimen/empty_dp"` а это чему равно?

Comment: <dimen name="empty_dp">0dp</dimen>

Comment: а почему у вас разный текст в этом виджете? вы его где-то устанавливаете кроме xml?

Comment: А где вы видите разный не вижу? Точки что внизу у подробнее не хватает?

Comment: Ну там есть еще вот такое в ресурсах <string name="bot_description_11">Активировать бота на 30 дней.\nДля покупки и активации этого \nбота необходимо оформить подписку.\n\n\nПодробнее..</string> Но я сомневаюсь что из-за этого А сам текст Подробнее.. я нигде не подставляю

Comment: да я про точки говорю, попробуйте закомментировать вообще этот виджет, будет ли откуда-то текст приходить сюда, также попробуйте убрать текст отсюда, и добавьте какой-то другой фон для виджета, чтобы понимать это два виджета, или два текста в одном виджете